# How to use getjson response variable in another getjson call within first getjson function?

Tags: javascript, html, getjson

i am using multiple getjson inside a javascript. I want to use the response of first getjson call which is a string like seasonID=44567 in another get json call as shown beleow (using **code** variable in second getJson)but unfortuently i keep getting bad request error. Could you guys help me fix this problem.Thanks

```
 <script>
    $.getJSON('http://www.site1.com/ok1.php&callback=?', function(data){
        //$('#output').html(data.contents);

     var siteContents = data.contents;   

var start = siteContents.indexOf('seasons=');
var end = siteContents.indexOf('&width=385&height=230', start);
var code = siteContents.substring(start, end);


    $.getJSON('http://www.site2.com/ok1.php?send="+code&callback=?', function(data){
    var siteContents2 = data.contents;
    document.myform2.outputtext2.value = siteContents2 ;
    });


    });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$.getJSON('http://www.site2.com/ok1.php?send=' + code + '&callback=?', function(data){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect quoting in the second `getJSON` call.

Instead of trying to construct the query string by appending, use the optional `data` argument to `getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.site2.com/ok1.php', { send: code, callback: '?' }, function(data){
```